# Can a trait implement an abstract method from a base class

Tags: groovy

I have a `ContactableMemberHandler` that is, right now, extending some `RecordListHandler`, but I also need a version of the contactable member handler that extend `SingleRecordHandler`. Of course, that version should contain the business concerns from the original...

The `BaseRecordHandler` look something like this:

```
class BaseRecordHandler<T> { 
    // a lot of implementation details irrelevant to this question...

    /**
     * 
     * @param records
     * @param onSubmit
     * @param onCheckDuplicate
     * @param onRetry
     */
    public void handle(List<T> records, Closure onSubmit, Closure onCheckDuplicate, Closure<T> onRetry) {
        boolean keepTrying = true;

        while(keepTrying) {
            try {
                onSubmit();
                keepTrying = false;
            } catch (StepFailedException ex) {
                this.handleFailure(ex, onSubmit, onCheckDuplicate, onRetry, records);
            }
        }

        for (T n : records)
            this.usedRecords.add(n);
    }

    protected abstract void handleFailure(StepFailedException ex, Closure onSubmit, Closure onCheckDuplicate, Closure<T> onRetry, List<T> newRecords) throws StepFailedException;

    // more irrelevant business logic
}
```

The `SingleRecordHandler` look like this:

```
@InheritConstructors
public abstract class SingleRecordHandler<T> extends BaseRecordHandler<T> {

    /**
     * @param record
     * @param onSubmit @throws StepFailedException
     * @param onCheckDuplicate
     * @param onRetry
     */
    public void handle(T record, Closure onSubmit, Closure<Boolean> onCheckDuplicate, Closure<T> onRetry) {
        this.handle([record], onSubmit, onCheckDuplicate, onRetry);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleFailure(StepFailedException ex, Closure onSubmit, Closure onCheckDuplicate, Closure<T> onRetry,
            List<T> newRecords) throws StepFailedException {
        if (onCheckDuplicate(ex)) {
            newRecords.add(onRetry());
        }
        else {
            newRecords.pop();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

and the `RecordListHandler` look something like this:

```
@InheritConstructors
public abstract class RecordListHandler<T> extends BaseRecordHandler<T> {

    @Override
    protected void handleFailure(StepFailedException ex, Closure onSubmit, Closure onCheckDuplicate, Closure<T> onRetry,
            List<T> newRecords) throws StepFailedException {
        int duplicateRecordIdx = onCheckDuplicate(ex);

        if (duplicateRecordIdx > -1) {
            newRecords.push(onRetry(duplicateRecordIdx));
        } else {
            newRecords.pop();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

...but what if we use traits?

It sounds like converting `SingleRecordHandler`,`RecordListHandler` to traits would solve this...

...but when we go to use them like:

```
public class ContactableMemberListHandler extends BaseRecordHandler<ContactableMemberModel> implements RecordListHandler<ContactableMemberModel> { 
   // ... business logic
}
```

will `handleFailure()` be implemented by the traits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it does. However `trait` methods are only `private` and `public`, hence you'd have to make the method `public`.

A `trait` can extend a `class`, but you'd still have to extend that base class when you go to use the trait...

Weird...